# ubuntu 22.04 on Asus Zenbook S 13 OLED

Tags: sound, asus

I have just bought a Asus Zenbook S13 and I'm having problems with the audio. The speakers are not working, but if I connect a bluetooth device (ex. headphones) it works perfectly.

this is my audio device (sudo lspci -v)

```
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1f12
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 103, IOMMU group 14
Memory at fc9c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it working by updating the BIOS.

If you have uninstalled Windows and cannot do the update from the MyAsus utility, here are the steps :

- download the last version of the [BIOS for Asus EZ Flash Utility](https://www.asus.com/fr/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-s-13-oled-um5302/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=Zenbook-S-13-OLED-UM5302-AMD-Ryzen-6000-series) on Asus website
- unzip the file and copy it to a USB key
- reboot and load into bios (press escape at boot and chose last option)
- go to advanced, firmware update, navigate to the file, update and reboot !